# Any reason NOT to use fiberglass when replacing old aluminum screening

Tags: screens

I have a screened porch, circa 1950 (on an 1869 house). The metal screening is directly tacked onto built-in frames, and the edges covered with thin molding.

It is sagging in places and riddled with small holes and numerous patches (some by me, some dating back decades). I would like to replace it all.

[image: screen door]

(Yes, I know the door itself needs much work.)

My inclination is to use fiberglass screening. It seems like it might be less prone to sagging and less prone to ripping. Is this so? Is there any reason to favor metal over fiberglass?

I am not concerned about historic accuracy on this project. And there are no pets or small children involved.

Comment: Just an opinion, but I prefer fiberglass to metal.  It seems to hold up better and is easier to work with.  I'm not aware of any way in which metal is superior.

Comment: You might want to research this, e.g., https://www.finehomebuilding.com/2009/07/01/how-to-choose-an-insect-screen